# prevent IE from use <br></br>

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

i am work  `contenteditable`  div and i change all emoji symbole with icon but i have problem in break line  (ie and edge) because they use `<br>` when press enter
and the `<br>` make to me many problems like the break line gone after replace emoji with icon and caret position would be wrong and other so  can i prevent the `<br>` and use \r\n or \n

what i try

```
tre.innerHTML =  tre.innerHTML.replace(/<br>/gi,'\n').replace(/<\/br>/gi,'');
```

here i replace all `<br>` with  `\n` work in edge but dosen't work in IE i mean edge show break line but IE dosen't

Answer (score 0):

Try applying this to the editable div in IE11 to get \n to act as a line break:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```